# Is it possible to create a responsive table that looks great on mobile in Semantic-UI-React?

Tags: responsive-design, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I have created a table using the Table component that is a child of the Grid component in Semantic-UI-React. The problem is that the table is too sensed on mobile.

I would really like to create something like this:
https://coinmarketcap.com/ 
where one column is fixed and the rest are not (talking about mobile view). 
I believe that this is not possible when using Semantic-UI-React.
At the very least I will like something like this:
https://www.coingecko.com/en
Where I can see the data in the table when I swipe left and right on mobile.

How can we achieve this using Semantic-UI-React?

Comment: I believe you can use `width={9}` to add more weight to some column, but as you already noticed, they are not fixed property. My personal experience with it is that you can't really fix the table layout. It'll be easy to simply use a basic table and then style it yourself, Or just choose `div` approach for each row, this way you can fix any `span` with `width`.

Comment: Have you looked into stacking for semantic-ui-react Table? I used the provided example for desktop and mobile views, and the table seems responsive in both screen sizes. More info at - https://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/table/#variations-unstackable

Comment: It's an improvement but still if I have around 8 columns where each width is ~2 than it still compasses it to show all 8 on mobile, at least from me testing right now